# How to remove zero elements from List<string>?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, removeall

Read couple of examples, but seems i`m doing something wrong.
Need to remove all "0" strings from a HUGE List without using hashtables.

Tryed using lambda samples from Stack Owerflow and MSDN examples, but looks i`m messing something up.

```
DataTable book = SQL.SqlGetTable(BookList.SelectedItem.ToString());
List<string> pagesExist = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < book.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][0].ToString());
}

var found = pagesExist.Find(x => x == "0");
if (found != null) 
    pagesExist.Remove(found);
```

I have a `pagesExist` list of 4000 string elements. 
Supposed that

```
var found = pagesExist.Find(x => x == "0");
```

will accumulate all zeroes in list and will remove them next string. But somehow found results in 0 elements

Comment: Why not prevent zeroes from being added in the first place? Also, `List<T>.Remove` is a very expensive operation because it involves moving all elements located after the removed item.

Comment: Instead of adding them then removing them, why don't you just NOT add it if it equals `"0"`?

Comment: Find will find 1 or 0 elements. Are you sure it didn't find 1?

Comment: @Dai way of thinking i missed when added validation code:)
Will try to prevent them from poping up then)
PS 
pagesExist.RemoveAll(item => item == "0");
Works as a zero removal lambda

Comment: @FireLancer pretty shure, run debug to make it visible - says 0.

Comment: Just BTW 4000 rows is not huge :)

Comment: @Silvermurk Could it maybe have been like "0 " (with space) or "0.0"? What is in `[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create the `pagesExist` list. Just filter out all non zero rows using a simple l[inq query over the `DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/linq-to-dataset). This way your entire code is reduced to only:

```
DataTable book = SQL.SqlGetTable(BookList.SelectedItem.ToString());
var result = book.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("FieldName") != 0);
```

*I am assuming that the column contains integers only. If not then keep the use `Field<string>` and filter for `!= "0"`*.

---

As a side note I would recommend looking into `SqlGetTable`. If it returns a `DataTable` it already brings all this data into memory from database, something that can be avoided with using linq directly over the DBMS using tools like linq-2-sql or linq-2-entities

Comment: Mins expanding a bit if i want to accumulate more then one field?
in case i used:
                pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][6].ToString());
                pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][8].ToString());
                pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][10].ToString());
                pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][12].ToString());
                pagesExist.Add(book.Rows[i][14].ToString());

Comment: @Silvermurk - what do you mean by accumulating more than one field? If you check what `result` contains then it is a collection with all the fields as in `book`. If `book` has many columns then so does `result`. It just removes those where the column specified has a value different than 0

Comment: @Silvermurk - do you mean you want all of the values of all those columns but then filter out the zeros? It will be best if you add some explanation to your question

Comment: You are correct. DataTable fields i`m listing are a reference fields to other book pages, so i need to collect all of those values into PagesExist List, and if some are not entered (like page has only one reference to the next page, instead of 3+ to others) - then i will have a "19" in book.Rows[i][0] - and 5 "0" in book.Rows[i][4] and so on
So i`m accumulating all values of those columns, and filtering out zero ones.

Comment: @Silvermurk - So I won't add a proper answer for this here as this is a followup question not described in the initial question and should be addressed in its own question. For here I will say that what you can do is first use SelectMany and specify many fields and after that use the Where to remove undesired items. This is of course only one way

Comment: Thanks for your answers) Will try it out, and in case something goes wrong will post new question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

```
pagesExist.RemoveAll(p => p == "0");
```